# Error message when I use xx.Contains in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying the following code inside an ASP MVC Razor file:

```
       var topic = ViewData["TopicID"];
        var mustBeReplaced = string.Empty;
        var topicValue = Model.Topic;
        var replaceResult = string.Empty;
        if (topic.Contains(topicValue)) {
            mustBeReplaced = "value=\"" + topicValue + "\"";
            replaceResult = mustBeReplaced + " selected=\"selected\"";
            topic = topic.Replace(mustBeReplaced, replaceResult);             
        }
```

But I get an error message:

object' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var topic = ViewData["TopicID"];
```

Returns object. You need to cast to string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    var topic = (string)ViewData["TopicID"];
    var mustBeReplaced = string.Empty;
    var topicValue = "11111";
    var replaceResult = string.Empty;
    if (topic.Contains(topicValue))
    {
        mustBeReplaced = "value=\"" + topicValue + "\"";
        replaceResult = mustBeReplaced + " selected=\"selected\"";
        topic = topic.Replace(mustBeReplaced, replaceResult);
    }
```